# Unitarity gauge in Higgs mechanism in P&S's QFT

Tags: standard-model, higgs, gauge-invariance, gauge

To my understanding, after spontaneous symmetry breaking, if we parametrized Higgs field:
$$\\ \phi(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ v+h(x) \end{array}\right)e^{i\pi(x)/v}, $$
we already ran out of $SU(2)$ gauge freedom (to put all v.e.v to one component), where $\pi(x)$ is the goldstone field.

Then we can take unitarity gauge to eliminate goldstone field, which leave
$$ \phi(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ v+h(x) \end{array}\right)$$
and in this step, we make use of $U(1)$ transformation. So up to this step, we ran out of all gauge freedoms.

However, I am confused about P&S's eq.(20.110):
$$ \phi(x)= U(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ v+h(x) \end{array}\right) \tag{20.110}$$
where $U(x)$ is a general $SU(2)$ gauge transformation according to the book. So why we still have $SU(2)$ gauge freedom here? What's the book's logic?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734990/local-su2-symmetry-breaking-and-unitary-gauge/735067#735067). (20.110) is a mere change of notation to the chiral Gürsey parameterization which you must have covered already in your study of [σ models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_model). It has not used up ***any*** gauge freedom, despite your mysterious first formula assertions to the contrary. Can you explain that backwards first expression?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you very much for your linked answer! My first expression maybe wrong, let's me check that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What P&S are saying in that section is just that starting from the general parametrization

$$ \phi(x)= U(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ v+h(x) \end{array}\right)$$

You can go to the unitary gauge by doing a transformation that eliminates the matrix $U(x)$. They haven't fixed the gauge yet in 20.110

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So unitary gauge break $SU(2)$ gauge freedom? Is there $U(1)$ gauge freedom in Higgs Mechanism? Thanks!

Comment: @Daren gauge freedom means that you have redundant degrees of freedom in your description, so before you can do any computation you have to explicitly choose a specific gauge where you don't have this freedom anymore. The unitary gauge is just a choice, but there are other possibilities (see the next chapter in P&S)

Comment: @Daren after the Higgs mechanism you are still left with a $U(1)$ gauge symmetry, subgroup of the original $SU(2)\times U(1)$, that is the one for the photon.

Comment: Thank you very much!